# Can 'xpath' be added to the list of tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

Could 'xpath' be added to the list of tags?

I am asking in relation to [Is there a software library that can treat a directory tree like an XPath data structure?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36705/is-there-a-software-library-that-can-treat-a-directory-structure-like-an-xpath-t)

Comment: I don’t exactly understand what your question is about, but I wonder: Is the library required to use XPath, or would something similar to XPath work, too?

Comment: Something similar to XPath is what is required, ie XPath like syntax for manipulating objects as files.

Comment: Okay, I think in that case the question should not get the "xpath" tag -- it should only be used if the software *has to* work with XPath. (Same with [tag:json] -- it should only be used if the software has to work with JSON.)

Comment: It would help to have an `xpath` tag though as someone is bound to need it in this day of web programming.

Comment: Shouldn't this now be *status-completed* as the tag has been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the [xpath](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xpath) tag to this question:

- [XPath GUI for Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18542/xpath-gui-for-windows)

I think it shouldn’t be added to the following questions (which includes yours), because in these questions XPath support seems to be only an option, not a requirement:

- [Is there a software library that can treat a directory tree like an XPath data structure?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36705/is-there-a-software-library-that-can-treat-a-directory-structure-like-an-xpath-t) ("XPath/JSON like instructions")
- [Software to search XML files which match an XPath](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32281/software-to-search-xml-files-which-match-an-xpath) ("which match a syntax like XPath or easier to use")
- [A program / site paste some xml, submit some sort of xpath query and return a result](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17850/a-program-site-paste-some-xml-submit-some-sort-of-xpath-query-and-return-a-re?s=4|0.6232) ("or some other xml querying language")

Comment: (And I [suggested a tag excerpt](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/23960).)